# Como fazer a query select e chamar a conexao na dao

Tags: java, mvc

Preciso de ajuda para estrutura da minha dao, como chamo a conexão, como faço o select dentro da função e como eu listo no meu main as informações que vem do select.

Como está até agora:

Conexão com o banco.

```
package Modal;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConexaoDB {

    Connection conexao = null;
    String driverDB = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    String rotaDB = "jdbc:sqlserver//10.0.0.14:1433;databasename=dbteste;user=db;password=123";

    public boolean ConectarDB(){

        try{
            Class.forName(driverDB);
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(rotaDB);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro: Não foi possível se conectar ao banco de dados" + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Modal

```
package Modal;

public class Tarefas {

    public String NrPlaca;

    public String getNrPlaca() {
        return NrPlaca;
    }
    public void setNrPlaca(String nrPlaca) {
        NrPlaca = nrPlaca;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package Cotroller;

import Dao.TarefasDao;
import Modal.Tarefas;

public class ControlTarefa {

    public void ListaTarefas(){
        Tarefas t = new Tarefas();
        TarefasDao tarefasdao = new TarefasDao();
        tarefasdao.ListaTarefas(t);
    }
}
```

dao

```
package Dao;

import Modal.Tarefas;

public class TarefasDao {

    public void ListaTarefas(Tarefas t){
        //chamar conexao com o banco
        //select
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das melhores maneiras é fazer o método da sua classe ConexaoDB retornar uma `Connection` através de um método estático. Ex.:

```
public static Connection conectaBD(){
    try {
        Class.forName(driverDB);
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(rotaDB);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Não foi possível conectar ao bd" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return conexao;
}
```

Depois em sua classe TarefasDao conecte o banco no construtor e realize as consultas SQL. Ex:

```
public class TarefasDao {

    Connection conexao;

    public TarefasDao() {
        conexao = ConexaoDB.conectaDB(); // utilização do método
    }

    public ArrayList<Tarefas> listaTarefas() {
        Statement sentenca;
        ResultSet registros;

        sentenca = conexao.createStatement();
        registros = sentenca.executeQuery("SELECT placa FROM tarefas");
        if (!registros.next()) {
            System.out.println("Nenhum registro encontrado");
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            List<Tarefas> tarefas = new ArrayList<Tarefas>();
            do {
                tarefas.add(new Tarefas());
                tarefas.get(i).setNrPlaca(registros.getString("placa"));
                i++;
            } while (registros.next());
            return tarefas;   
        }
        sentenca.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Depois no seu controller dá pra criar um objeto de TarefasDao e chamar o método `listaTarefas()` e você terá uma lista com todas as placas das tarefas:

```
public class ControlTarefa {

    public void ListarTarefas(){
        TarefasDao tarefasdao = new TarefasDao();
        List<Tarefas> tarefas = tarefasdao.listaTarefas();
    }
}
```

Há algumas coisas que precisam ser destacadas:

Pelo que entendi você quer retornar as informações de várias tarefas, mas passa somente um objeto ao método `listaTarefas()` do seu `Dao` sendo que deveria passar uma lista ou simplesmente não passar nada e apenas retornar a lista, como eu fiz.

Lembre-se que por convenção, nomes de métodos começam com letra minúscula em java, assim como o nome correto do seu controller seria `TarefasController`.

Comment: Entendi, não mexo muito com java consegue me mostrar como mando estes dados para a view, um exemplo ?

Comment: Que tipo de view você possui? JSP, swing, fxml?

Comment: A view é do tipo JSP

Comment: Você passa pelo seu controller através do método `setAttribute` da interface [`ServletRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html), e depois acessa via JSP assim: `${tarefa.getNrPlaca}`. Mas Isso ainda depende de muitos fatores, vai utilizar spring? Se não, o quão bem você conhece sobre `ServletRequest`? Já possui as views criadas? Essa parte é mais complexa, talvez seja tema de outra pergunta.

Comment: Ta ok, vou ver se faço outra pergunta sobre isso.